# Fetch range of columns with PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have an excel file that looks something like this
[image: Excel file with column headers]

What I want to do is read the data from all rows but not all columns. I want to fetch data for all rows from column **A** to **E**. Currently, I am able to read the entire row (column **A** to **CL**) with this code

```
// Read data from excel file
$reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
// Convert read data to array
$sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
// Put captured array to use
for ($row=1; $row <= count($sheetData) ; $row++) {
 $xData = "'".implode("','",$sheetData[$row])."'";
}
print_r($xData);
exit;
```

Could someone guide me achieve this? I tried

```
// Specify columns to fetch data from
$cols = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K');
// Put captured array to use
for ($row=1; $row <= count($sheetData) ; $row++) {
  foreach ($cols as $col) {
    $xData = "'".implode("','",$sheetData[$col.$row])."'";
  }
}
print_r($xData);
exit;
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Try this ,`$last_row=spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();`  `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:E'.$last_row, NULL, True, True);`

Answer (score 3):

Use utility helper e.g. [PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php) to convert column to/from index/letter.

```
$ws = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$firstColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString('A'); // A->1
$lastColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString('E'); // E->5
$firstRow = 1;
$lastRow = 4;
$data = [];
for($row = $firstRow; $row <= $lastRow; ++$row){
    for($col = $firstColumnIndex; $col <= $lastColumnIndex; ++$col){
        $data[$row][$col] = $ws->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
    }
}
print_r($data, true); // data are now collected in 2-dimensional array
```

There are also other methods such as `stringFromColumnIndex`, `coordinateFromString`, `indexesFromString`, `buildRange`, `rangeBoundaries`, `rangeDimension`, `getRangeBoundaries` etc. which may come handy, but seems not so well documented.